# Labels inconsistent across jobs returned results

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

You guys @ jobs thought you could get away from me...

I have some free time today...:).

Labels when you filter for jobs are inconsistent.  At the top you have this:

[image]

Yet at the bottom of all of these jobs you have this:

[image]

Font size, color, and style should be consistent as well but they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the note! Label fix is incoming. Re: styling differences - this is by design.